# JAXB : Custom name for unmarshalled json array

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jax-rs

I am trying to unmarshall a list of error objects.

```
requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).entity(
                    new GenericEntity<List<Error>>(errors){})
                    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).build());
```

The unmarshalled JSON looks like

```
{"error":[{"code":5,"detail":"app level of request, 2, does not meet the minimum required app level, 5"}]}
```

However I want my json array to be named `errors` instead of `error`. This is the java class definition of `Error`

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Error {

    @XmlElement
    private Integer code;

    @XmlElement
    private String detail;

    public Error(Integer code, String detail) {
        this.code = code;
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    public Error() {}
    }
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, it uses @XmlRootElement. So you will need to use [@JsonRootName](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonRootName.html)

```
@JsonRootName("errors")
@XmlRootElement
public class Error {
```